# How to check if two rectangles overlap in SDL2?

Tags: c++, sdl-2, 2d-games

I am creating a game using SDL2 which creates 200 objects of a class `Star` and prints onto the screen all 200 as 2px x 2px rects in random locations. I created a player class which creates a 10px x 10px rect that can be moved using WASD.
I created a vector of type Star which holds all 200 stars with identifier `allStars`.
The game loop runs three functions: `Event()`, `Update()`, and `Render()`. In `Event()`, there is a piece of code which intitiates a for loop which iterates through `allStars` checks first to see whether the x-coordinate of the star matches with that of the player box, and second checks to see if the y-coordinate matches with the player box.

```
else if (state[SDL_SCANCODE_SPACE]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < allStars.size(); i++) {
            if (allStars[i].starPosX > player.rect.x && allStars[i].starPosX < (player.rect.x + player.rect.w)) {
                if (allStars[i].starPosY > player.rect.y && allStars[i].starPosY < (player.rect.y + player.rect.h)) {
                    std::cout << allStarsNames[i] << ": " << allStars[i].starPosX << ", " << allStars[i].starPosY << ", " << allStars[i].starColor << ", " << allStars[i].starMass << "\n";
                    std::cout << "\n\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[The game rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlvKE.png)

`starPosX` and `starPosY` are attributes of the `Star` class which are used to give value to the x- and y-coordinates of the rect which is created for the star.
I was attempting to see if the program would print information about the star when this code was run in order to check if it was working, however the information of the star is never printed. I can't seem to find a correct method of creating a hitbox for a rect in SDL2. Is there a procedure I could use to solve this issue?

So far I have made adjustsments to the rect in the player class and how I have referred to its position. This can be seen in how I have wrote `player.rect.x`, whereas previously I had referred to another attribute of the `Player` class, `playerX` and `playerY`. My reasoning for creating so many versions of the x- and y-coordinates was from avoiding a whole other problem entirely. The `Player` class is as follows:

```
class Player {
public:
    int playerX = 250;
    int playerY = 250;
    int playerW = 10;
    int playerH = 10;
    SDL_Rect rect;
    Player() {
        rect.x = playerX;
        rect.y = playerY;
        rect.w = playerW;
        rect.h = playerH;
    }
    void UpdatePlayerPos(SDL_Renderer *renderer) {
        rect.x = playerX;
        rect.y = playerY;
    }
    void DrawPlayer(SDL_Renderer *renderer) {
        SDL_RenderDrawRect(renderer, &rect);
    }
};
```

The `UpdatePlayerPos()` method is called during the `Update()` function during the gameloop. It seems that my logic of how to check whether or not two rectangles overlap one another is the logical way to go about it, however I cannot seem to find where the issue is located that causes the print out statement to not execute.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't seem to find a correct method of creating a hitbox for a rect in SDL2. Is there a method I could use to solve this issue?

[`SDL_HasIntersection()`](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/release-2.26.3/include/SDL_rect.h#L133-L147):

```c
/**
 * Determine whether two rectangles intersect.
 *
 * If either pointer is NULL the function will return SDL_FALSE.
 *
 * \param A an SDL_Rect structure representing the first rectangle
 * \param B an SDL_Rect structure representing the second rectangle
 * \returns SDL_TRUE if there is an intersection, SDL_FALSE otherwise.
 *
 * \since This function is available since SDL 2.0.0.
 *
 * \sa SDL_IntersectRect
 */
extern DECLSPEC SDL_bool SDLCALL SDL_HasIntersection(const SDL_Rect * A,
                                                     const SDL_Rect * B);
```

Comment: Thank you. I can attempt to use this function, I was not aware it existed. I would have to change a few things, since the rect of each star is not recorded, but rather a new rect is created using the DrawRect() function that I wrote.